# Regex to match links that arent already marked up

Tags: regex, url

I want to match any URL that isn't already enclosed in an href.  i.e I want to ignore the following.

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/whatever">
```

I'm trying to write a regex to automatically find urls, so that I can turn them into marked up a hrefs.

The issue I'm having is dealing with urls that have already been marked up (The documents contain a mix of marked up and not marked up urls).

Comment: Another duplicate...: [regex-to-turn-urls-into-links-without-messing-with-existing-links-in-the-text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980902/regex-to-turn-urls-into-links-without-messing-with-existing-links-in-the-text)

Answer (score 0):

Use negative look ahead to see if an url does NOT have `</a>` ahead of it

```
your_regex(?!\s*</a>)
```