# creating hyperlinks from plain text

Tags: php, regex

I use this code to make plain texts hyperlinks.

```
 $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', 
    '<a target="_blank" href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text); 
      $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tps://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', 
    '<a target="_blank" href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text); 
  $text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)', 
    '\\1<a target="_blank" href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text); 
  $text = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})', 
    '<a target="_blank" href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
```

But it doesnt work when text is www.domain.com or domain.com or subdomain.domain.com

How can i make it work with them ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I linkify urls in a string with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507436/how-do-i-linkify-urls-in-a-string-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are heaps of duplicates of this question, which is the very fact that makes it more difficult to find the right one. Accept this list instead:

- [How do I linkify urls in a string with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507436/how-do-i-linkify-urls-in-a-string-with-php)
- [regex to turn URLs into links without messing with existing links in the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980902/regex-to-turn-urls-into-links-without-messing-with-existing-links-in-the-text)
- [PHP - Function To Find Links In Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762666/php-function-to-find-links-in-text)
- [Need a good regex to convert URLs to links but leave existing links alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287144/need-a-good-regex-to-convert-urls-to-links-but-leave-existing-links-alone)

But since you already have something that you think works for you, there would be the option to just add the edge case. Finding `sub.domain.com` is not easy and likely leads to false positives. But converting them to http:// urls so the other rules pick them up would be possible by applying this first:

```
$text = preg_replace('#(?<!://)w+\.\w+\.(com|net|org|\w\w)\b\S*#', "http://$0", $text);
$text = preg_replace('#(?<!://)www\.\S+#', "http://$0", $text);
```

Instead of `\S` you could use your lengthy character class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: [[function] AutoLink (converts URLS into links inside a string)](http://www.gidforums.com/t-1816.html)