# PHP regular expressions - replacing text with hyperlinks

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently working on some bespoke blog software. Under the management panel a user may create a post and PHP should then parse any text that matches my pattern and replace it with a live hyperlink accordingly. It works well for simple posts, however when a large post is given the the hyperlink is created with much more than the text link and extends to a whole paragraph of text.

Here's my PHP:

```
function TextToLinks($input)
{
    $pattern = "/www\.(.*)\.(.*?)(\s|$)/";
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, "Utilities::LinksCallback", $input);
}

function LinksCallback($matches)
{
    return "<a href='http://{$matches[0]}'>{$matches[0]}</a>";
}
```

I can't work out how to make the pattern more strict.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex to turn URLs into links without messing with existing links in the text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980902/regex-to-turn-urls-into-links-without-messing-with-existing-links-in-the-text)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+text+urls+to+links+php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the non-greedy flag `?` also to the first `.*`.

```
$pattern = "/www\.(.*?)\.(.*?)(\s|$)/";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly now. Just one character needed!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good way to match hyperlinks. It'll break if the links are already fully formed (e. g. the poster already put `http://` in front of it, and it'll miss all links that don't start with `www.`.

If that's not a problem, you might get away with `/\bwww\.(\S*)\.(\S*)\b/`.

`\S` only allows non-whitespace characters to match, and `\b` assert that the match starts/ends at a word boundary.

For more background information, read [this blog post by Jan Goyvaerts](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I did think this however it will not be a problem for the user of the software as www. will only be used as they look "nicer" :D

Comment: In that case, you're on the safe side with that regex.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. too. Those flags are very useful and save time replacing the need for longer patterns.